# Arc Dark Theme Fine Tuning

Tags: themes, calendar

I have just started to customize my Ubuntu a little bit and found the Arc-Dark theme to be exactly what I am looking for.

There are some small things though.

The color of the calendar on top is still white, and the font of the notifications and inside the calendar are off. This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

I would like to see the calendar being the same darker color, and maybe having the day numbers font in white.

Also the font color of the search bar is off. There is text, but it is just as dark as the background.

[image]

It's only visible when you hover over the search bar.

[image]

How would I go about changing/tweaking these things? Or did I do something wrong during the installation?

**Edit:**
UnKNOWn has answered my question (accepted answer).

The css-file was, in my instance, found at `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`. I made the small changes to `.calendar` and `.search-entry`, saved the file (with sudo rights) and reloaded the theme by simply re-applying it with Gnome-Tweaks!

Comment: Can you share the link to arc dark theme? I will install n see.

Comment: You can install the theme with ```sudo apt-get install arc-theme```!
[This](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme) is the repo.

Comment: Hi reloading is done by Alt+F2 input 'rt' hit enter!!! Once you edit n saved the css file.

Comment: @UnKNOWn ah, that's much easier! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic areas to edit as per your wish from the arc-dark theme css file are below..

```
.search-entry {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: blue; } /* edited this line  */
```

[image]

```
.calendar {
background-color: blue; /* added this line */
  margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

[image]

Comment: Hey UnKNOWn! Thanks for answering my question. Where would I be able to find this css file? And if I have edited it, do I have to reload any settings, or should the changes show up immediately?

Comment: Nevermind, found the css file! Had to reload the theme to see the changes though. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Askubuntu!

Have you tried lxappearance?

```
 sudo apt install lxappearance
```

in a terminal:

```
 lxappearance
```

or just search it in super > lxappearance

Is it like this you mean?

A similar question about appearance customizing was previously asked here, actually :)
[image]

Comment: Hey William! Thanks for the suggestion. Although I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I'm looking to specifically adjust the color of the calendar on top and the color of the font in a few spots. This seems to only let me change the full theme, font, and some other small things.

Comment: Yeah, it's good to get to know some tools anyways! So thanks again for suggesting, gnome-tweaks seems to do kind of the same thing with some small extras. I'm gonna keep looking, until someone comes along, and will keep this thread updated if I find something!

Comment: Unfortunately, lxappearance does not apply to the GNOME Shell theme which is governed by other means than the general appearance of GTK 2/3 windows. −1

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing it out!