# Calendar (notification panel) in the Arc-Black shell theme is unreadable

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes, calendar, notification-area

Since I renamed my home folder I've gotten many bugs including the following one where the calendar in my Arc-Black theme appears to be white and unreadable, also, you have the Themes I'm using right now in the Tweeks screenshot down below

[image]

[image]

Comment: You solved it, Thank you so much

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is posted by the user [UnKNOWN](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/unknown):

> Related? [askubuntu.com/a/1282050/739431](http://askubuntu.com/a/1282050/739431) – UnKNOWn 7