# Arc-Dark accessing notifaction panel in .css file

Tags: gnome, themes, notification

The Arc-Dark GNOME Shell theme has some [bad configurations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281917/arc-dark-theme-fine-tuning/1282050). Since I cannot ask about it in the comments (<50 reputation), I'm asking it here:

What is the name of the black text that is dimly shown in the notifications? I need to know how to search for a possible solution to the lack of contrast between the black text and its dark gray background in the below screenshot which makes it difficult to read.

[image: black writings]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot the white text is the *title* of the notification and the black text is the *body* text of the notification. The color of the text is referred to as the font color and the color of the background is referred to as the background color.

Example CSS using "body" as a selector:

```css
body {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: But do you know what exactly to look for in the .css file. There are 89 lines containing the keyword "notification" and I don't know which is the correct one.

Comment: Please copy/paste your CSS code in a question at that you ask at Stack Overflow Q&A. That question is about programming. It's is off topic at Ask Ubuntu, but it's on topic at Stack Overflow.